# Bad operand types error

Tags: java, operands

I am getting this error when trying to add input validation to a program that I am working on:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '||' first type: boolean; second type: java.lang.String
```

Here's my code:

```
String x = scan.nextLine();

while (!x.toLowerCase().equals("buy a lamborghini")||("donate")||("do you know who i am")||("go sailing")||("drink fine wine")||("invest")||("gamble"))
{
    System.out.println("Please choose a valid option");
}
```

The error is highlighted around the "donate" portion of the while condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use an `or` operand with a `String` and a `boolean`

What you want is something like this:

```
while (!(x.toLowerCase().equals("buy a lamborghini") || 
    x.toLowerCase().equals("donate") ||
    x.toLowerCase().equals("do you know who i am") ||
    x.toLowerCase().equals("go sailing") ||
    x.toLowerCase().equals("drink fine wine") ||
    x.toLowerCase().equals("invest") ||
    x.toLowerCase().equals("gamble")))
{
    //...
}
```

I'm assuming you're making some sort of adventure game -- if you want to make this cleaner, your loop for performing actions should look something like this:

```
if (x.toLowerCase().equals("buy a lamborghini"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("donate"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("do you know who i am"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("buy a lamborghini"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("go sailing"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("drink fine wine"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("invest"))
{
}
else if (x.toLowerCase().equals("gamble"))
{
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error! Invalid Input!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other note is that `x.toLowerCase().equals(String str)` can be refactored to `x.equalsIgnoreCase(String str)`. They do the same thing, but the second is perhaps more readable and more often used.